# Create new POI in SXA Map component gives "CreateDataSource not found exception"

Tags: sxa

I am trying to create new POI from Map properties dialog with SXA but getting this exception:

> Method "CreateDataSource" not found in
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.FieldEditorForm. (method:
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.Dispatch(String command)).

Steps to reproduce:
I clicked on "Edit component map item" (1) and then in POI field, I clicked on "Create" (2). Exception raised (3).

[image]

Anyone encountered the same? Is this a bug or something that I need to configure?

I am on Sitecore 9 Update 2 and SXA 1.7.1 with Habitat Home instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is actually an issue in the 1.7.1 release. Those buttons - `Create`, `Copy to` - are already removed in 1.8. They should be only available in data source selection dialogue and because of the fact that it's the same tree control by mistake they have been automatically added also to this POI selection field.

Please use a context menu to add new POI items:

[image]

Comment: I have used Content Editor to overcome this issue as you suggested. Thanks for clarification Dawid

Comment: will that be counted as a bug @daru ?

Comment: This is already fixed - it was registered as a bug in our backlog.